# If stored procedure failed then Get output variables values into ssis variables in Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to get output messages from SP into SSIS variable inside Execute SQL Task. I am able to get messages if stored proc execute successfully, but in case stored procedures raise errors, then variables remain empty as below-

[image: Calling SP with output variable inside Execute Sql Taks]

[image: Paramter mapping for output variables]

[image: Stored procedure code with output variables and raise error]

Now in case sp execute completed successfully then ssis variables got data,
but in case of sp execute with errors then ssis variables remain empty and execute SQL task component fails (which is desired behaviour).
Please guide. Thankyou!

Comment: *"but in case stored procedures raise errors"* What are those errors? Why are you pasting SQL as an image, and what is that `IF 1=1` there for? When does `1` *not* equal `1`?

Comment: @Larnu, this sp is just an example to explain the problem statement. SP raise user-defined errors and i need to retrieve it in ssis and then use them further in my system.

Answer (score 0):

If execute SQL task fails, output variables are not populated.
Best option is to change your stored procedure and wrap all the code in the try/catch block. This way you will be able to always populate variables, just be sure to fail SSIS package if you receive internal errors.

If you use RAISERROR  in the stored procedure, only information available to SSIS is the error message withing the RAISERROR statement. You can retrieve this information by creating OnError handler in SSIS and then it will be available in the system variable: "System::ErrorDescription"